# I updated my own theme's code and css

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

I have mt theme folder in my computer, where I did all the updates. Now I want to upload the new version of my theme with the changes I did. My question here: Do I just upload the theme folder via FTP and overwrite the existing one? Will this damage or change my posts or it will just update the theme design? I did this last night, but I'm afraid it changes everything...

Comment: Depends whether you saved information in the database. I would suggest moving the currently-live theme folder to another location outside of wp-content. That way WP will not recognize it but it's safely backed up and easy to revert. Then try uploading your new version. If things aren't all working quite right you have probably saved info in the database and need to either make those changes in production as you did on the test site, or sync your databases (if you haven't changed any posts in production, you might be able to use a database migration plugin to push from your local install)

Comment: I download the whole wp install from cpanel, and copy my theme's folder to work on it locally. So I move the wp theme folder outside themes folder and upload the one I did... right? How can I know if everything is well saved in the db?

Comment: If the only edits you made were to the files, then FTPing the new folder up will work. But many themes also save info in the database. If there are any settings in wp-admin that you changed, those would be in the db. For example, if you did anything at all in the Customizer.

Comment: I did update it. I worked but not as well as I exprected. Sorry, I'm new to all this wp world. I updated it but I have a folder where I have an extra css. I used <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/estilos.css"> to show it as well, that part I didn't changed it, but now it doesn't show that part of the css. I tried copying that css to the styles.css but it doesn't work either... :(

Comment: Sounds like a good time to read up more on theme development. For stylesheets it's best practice to actually enqueue them rather than just add a link. Also, caching may be entering into this - if you have a cache plugin or use a host that caches things for you, or use a CDN, your CSS files may be cached. Or it could be that you referenced the file wrong - if you view the source on your live site is the link to estilos.css clickable and working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use case for a local development environment. But, yes, if all you did was change files in the theme, then nothing that was saved to your database will be altered. If you are worried about things breaking, then I suggest getting a local copy of your WP install running and test things out there before pushing anything to your live site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create child theme and upload new files here to prevent overwriting the old files.

How to use child themes you can [read here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Answer (score 0):

Uploading new version of the theme should not mess up your post content, unless you have some crazy code which is actually updating data randomly...

What I am saying is

1. it's safe in 99.9% of cases
2. it's never 100% - so take some pre-cautions

What can you do to minimize the risk?

1. Have a staging environment - basically, clone live site (to a subdomain, for example), upload new theme there, test
2. Have a full backup. Database + files. You can use plugin or do it manually by archiving all files and saving a dump of database. This way you can roll back easily if something goes wrong